# Firefox driver for selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, webdriver, driver

where to download the firefox driver for selenium?

I only find this, and herer is not the driver file for download
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

NOTE: I already have Selenium Webdriver IDE for Firefox but the script aks me to find firefox driver
Can I use firefox in for webdriver in C# or its only capable for java?

Comment: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/selenium-dotnet-2.46.0.zip

Comment: Thanks!  and a stupid question: Must I add this in the variables system as I did with the chromedriver? how-where I must install the 2 folder you send me?

Comment: I only have to drag and drop the content of the folder 40 into a visual studio folder? or how must I install?

Comment: can I use firefox driver for selenium code in C#?

Comment: You just have to add the selenium dlls to your project. They already contain the drivers for the browsers that you want to test. A little bit of googling on `how to add references to your project` will help you.

Comment: thanks and sorry, perhaps it only work with java and not with C#?

Comment: of course it does work with c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach for C# projects is to install the WebDriver NuGet, because if there are any updates it will be notified. Just install NuGet Manager and search for WebDriver.

After that just use the following code:

```
IWebDriver driverOne = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebDriver driverTwo = new InternetExlorerDriver("C:\\PathToMyIeDriverBinaries\");
```

The FirefoxDriver is included in the NuGet. However, you need to download manually the ChromeDriver from here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

You can find ten mins tutorial with images here: 
http://automatetheplanet.com/getting-started-webdriver-c-10-minutes/

Comment: I have did all what you say here and in your web but a windows ask me to find "FirefoxDriverServer.cs" (and i have added correctly the references), here a capture of the request: http://i.imgur.com/TErjqH6.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You just need to include/import driver to your project if you want to use firefox unlike for CHROME you need to store the jar file or Exe to a particular location and then then you just need to call it in your project

### demo program

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Firefox {

         public void returnFirefoxBrowser(){
             WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }
```

### chrome

```
         File file = new File(
              "//Users//Documents//workspace//SELENIUM//chromedriver");
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
         WebDriver driver_chrome;
         driver_chrome = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: I only have to drag and drop the content of the folder 40 into a visual studio folder? or how must I install?

Comment: jar file works with eclipse programs, if you want with c# google for dll for driver of chrome or browser required.