# Selenium tests with Chrome driver on build agent without chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-headless

We have a set of [Selenium tests in c# project](http://executeautomation.com/blog/running-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-selenium-c/) with xunit.
We use headless chrome and tests are running just fine on PCs with Chrome installed.

However, on build agents we don't have Chrome, so we receive an exception `cannot find Chrome binary`.

Is there any way to ship Chrome within test project as a standalone exe, so we don't have to install it on the servers?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just include the binary with a reference path.
Alternatively, you could use headless or any number of other binaries which are built right into newer versions of selenium. IE: No actual need for a binary if you use the Selenium code base.

Comment: could you suggest a nuget package containing chrome.exe? where could I take actual chrome.exe from to include it as reference?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207067/firefox-driver-for-selenium 
The answer here will direct you.

Comment: the answer there is about chromedriver.exe. It's included in Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver nuget package, there's no problem with it. The problem is there's no chrome.exe

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

Comment: again, it's chromedriver.exe in the zip archive, and I don't have any problem with it. It's referenced, it's included in bin, it's found on BuildAgent. The problem is, it still requires chrome.exe to work and I don't know where to take chrome.exe from

Comment: Oh, misunderstood. You could try PhantomJS as it does not require any external applications to be installed. Or, just install Chrome on the build agent and point to it. Use ChromeOptions and specify:
ChromeOptions cromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

//Location of browser binary/.exe file
cromeOptions.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");

cromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
cromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
cromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
cromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");

WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(cromeOptions);

Comment: I was using PhantomJS like that before, just wanted to switch to Chrome this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to achieve what you are after, via portable Chromium bundle

> within test project as a standalone exe

Basic steps are:

- download desired version from [their page](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html)
- unzip
- run `chrome.exe`

Main advantages of the portable browser are that you can carry it with your projects anywhere, avoiding installation and dabbling with the windows registry.

It is true that Chromium is the open-source version of Chrome itself, but is efficient enough just like Chrome. Keep  in mind that there are some functionality differences, when it comes to flash and PDF.

Comment: thanks, it seems to be exactly what I needed. Will test and accept the answer :)

Comment: Is there a NuGet package for this? I haven't found any.

Comment: Me neither @Piedone, but one can always create and maintain such :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess there are licensing issues though.